# Counting actors and storing and displaying their name and role

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java and I'm attempting to learn off different sites and videos and I've been stuck on a problem for a couple of days now and I'm wondering can anyone help out. What I'm trying to do is ask the user how many key actors are in a film. Then i want to ask the actors name and the role they play in the film, this should be asked for each actor for however many the user specified are in the film before finally displaying the actors name and his role?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int actorCount;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("How many actors are in the film? ");
        actorCount = kb.nextInt();


        for (int k = 1; k <= actorCount ; k++)
        {
            float actor, character; 
            System.out.println("What is the actors name? ");
            actor = kb.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("What is " + actor + "'s character?");
            character = kb.nextFloat();


            System.out.print(actor + " - " + character);

        }

        kb.close();
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use `float` for text values instead of `String` ? I think you should take a look at **[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)** and **[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)**

Comment: The actor 25.42 is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would have done:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class rough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    int actorCount;
    String output = "";

    actorCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many actors are in the film? "));

    for (int k = 1; k <= actorCount ; k++)
    {
        String actor, character; 
        actor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the actors name?");
        character = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " +actor + "s character?");


        output +=  actor + " - " + character + "\n";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }
}
```

Remember that if you want all of the roles/actors to be printed at the same time you must put the print outside the for loop and store the roles/actors to some output String. Moreover, I cannot see why you have used a float variable for the roles/actors a String would be the most logical.

Answer (score 0):

So you should do it in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int actorCount;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("How many actors are in the film? ");
    actorCount = kb.nextInt();

    String[][] actorValues = new String[actorCount][2];

    for (int k = 0; k < actorCount ; k++)
    {
        String actor, character; 
        System.out.println("What is the actors name? ");
        actor = kb.next();

        System.out.println("What is " + actor + "'s character?");
        character = kb.next();


        System.out.print(actor + " - " + character +"\n");
        actorValues[k][0] = actor;
        actorValues[k][1] = character;

    }


    //Printout the Characters in the List
    System.out.println("All Actors:");
    for (int i = 0; i < actorValues.length; i++) {
        String[] strings = actorValues[i];
        System.out.println("Actorssname: "+strings[0]+" Character:"+strings[1]);

    }

    kb.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: It will work for you - you have to change the method "nextFloat()" to "next()". It allows you to read a String.